# How to actually solve for the eigenstates in the adiabatic version of Grover's algorithm

Tags: grovers-algorithm, adiabatic-model

The [adiabatic](https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/0107015.pdf) version of Grover's algorithm says that the eigenstates of the Hamiltonian $H(t)=(1-\frac{t}{T})H_0+\frac{t}{T}H_m$ (equation 10 in the linked paper) can be used to solve the eigenvalue problem (equation 2) $H(t)E_{k,t}=E_k(t)E_{k,t}$. However, **it does not actually explain how to do this**. A [later paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/0206003.pdf) by Vazirani et al derives the same result in section 5: Quantum Adiabatic Searching, without actually doing it.

How would you actually solve the equation in this case?

Comment: Take inspiration from the normal version of Grover's: the only relevant subspace has a basis of just two states. The same is true here, for the same states, from which you can complete the diagonalisation.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm still struggling with it. If it's not too much to ask, could you be a bit more explicit? Fundamentally, I don't know how to solve these types of eigenvalue problems because I have an engineering background, not a physics one, and haven't touched 'pure' QM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the same notation as in the paper, we have $H_0=I-|\psi_0\rangle\langle\psi_0|$ and $H_m=I-|m\rangle\langle m|$, such that $\tilde H(s)=(1-s) H_0 + s H_m$ is the adiabatic Hamiltonian.

In order to obtain the relevant energy gap, let's define the residual vector $$|r\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{N-1}} \sum_{i\neq m} |i\rangle,$$
such that $|\psi_0\rangle=\frac{\sqrt{N-1}}{\sqrt{N}} |r\rangle + \frac{1}{\sqrt{N}} |m\rangle$.
Within this basis, the Hamiltonian is diagonalizable by hand.
To see this, we rewrite the initial Hamiltonian $H_0$ as
$$H_0 = I-|\psi_0\rangle\langle\psi_0|=I-\frac{N-1}{N}|r\rangle\langle r|-\frac{1}{N}|m\rangle\langle m| - \frac{\sqrt{N-1}}{N}(|m\rangle\langle r| + |r \rangle\langle m|).$$
The adiabatic Hamiltonian in matrix notation in the $|m\rangle$, $|r\rangle$ basis is then
$$\tilde H(s) = (1-s) H_0 + s H_m = \begin{pmatrix}1 - s - \frac{1-s}{N} & -(1-s)\frac{\sqrt{N-1}}{N}\\-(1-s)\frac{\sqrt{N-1}}{N}&1-(1-s)\frac{N-1}{N}\end{pmatrix}.$$
The eigenvalues of this 2x2 Matrix are
$$\lambda_{1,2} = \frac{1}{2} \pm \sqrt{\frac{1}{4} - \frac{N-1}{N}(1-s)s},$$
which yields the energy gap in Eq. (13) of the paper you linked.

Hope this helps.